# Using Plyr to generate p-values (t-test) for two factors

Tags: r

I am looking to generate a set of p-values (one row per gene) for each gene using a simple t-test. I have the dataframe similar to what is below:

```
     SampleID Gene  val         Type

1   13366   GENE_A  3.15031629      Normal
2   13366   GENE_B  3.75717258      Normal
3   13366   GENE_C  3.57842994      Normal
4   13368   GENE_A  0.68801833      Affected
5   13368   GENE_B  2.78232529      Affected
6   13368   GENE_C  4.99150585      Affected
7   13370   GENE_A  3.22589363      Normal
8   13370   GENE_B  3.51548931      Normal
9   13370   GENE_C  3.93326487      Normal
10  34398   GENE_A  0.41194238      Affected
11  34398   GENE_B  3.23511072      Affected
12  34398   GENE_C  3.06637922      Affected
13  34400   GENE_A  3.26666659      Normal
14  34400   GENE_B  3.98581901      Normal
15  34400   GENE_C  3.94751765      Normal
16  34413   GENE_A  2.02822848      Affected
17  34413   GENE_B  2.97689035      Affected
18  34413   GENE_C  4.26453415      Affected
```

The resultant dataframe in this set would just have 3 rows (1 per gene) and an additional column for the p-value comparing values of Normal vs Affected for each gene. I'd like to use plyr to do this ideally. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
df <- read.csv(textConnection("SampleID,Gene,val,Type
1,13366,GENE_A,3.15031629,Normal
2,13366,GENE_B,3.75717258,Normal
3,13366,GENE_C,3.57842994,Normal
4,13368,GENE_A,0.68801833,Affected
5,13368,GENE_B,2.78232529,Affected
6,13368,GENE_C,4.99150585,Affected
7,13370,GENE_A,3.22589363,Normal
8,13370,GENE_B,3.51548931,Normal
9,13370,GENE_C,3.93326487,Normal
10,34398,GENE_A,0.41194238,Affected
11,34398,GENE_B,3.23511072,Affected
12,34398,GENE_C,3.06637922,Affected
13,34400,GENE_A,3.26666659,Normal
14,34400,GENE_B,3.98581901,Normal
15,34400,GENE_C,3.94751765,Normal
16,34413,GENE_A,2.02822848,Affected
17,34413,GENE_B,2.97689035,Affected
18,34413,GENE_C,4.26453415,Affected"))


ddply(df,
      .(Gene),
      summarize,
     pval= t.test(val[Type=='Normal'],val[Type == 'Affected'])$p.value)
```